# Remove stopwords with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, variables, stop-words

I want to remove stopwords from text but fail to use regex and variables properly. For example I remove the stopword "he" but this also affects the word "when". I tried to use word boundaries like this:

`new RegExp('\b'+stopwords[i]+'\b' , 'g')` but doesn't work...

See a small example here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5Az/)

```
var stopwords = ['as', 'at', 'he', 'the', 'was'];
for (i = 0; i < stopwords.length; i++) {
    str = str.replace(new RegExp(stopwords[i], 'g'), '');
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this maybe

```
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b('+stopwords.join('|')+')\\b', 'g'), '');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dx5Az/1/)

You have to double escape in RegExp, and you could just join everything creating

```
/\b(as|at|he|the|was)\b/g
```

Comment: Nice! Do you know if this join is faster than the `for` loop? Consider that I have a list of 300 stopwords.

Comment: I'd assume it is, as it creates one single regex and does the replace once, and not 300 times.

Comment: Can you explain the use of `.join('|')` Sorry but I noticed this difference now :-)

Comment: You need to enclose the joined words in a group for the `\b` anchors to work properly, i.e. the pattern should be: `/\b(?:word1|word2)\b/` instead of: `/\bword1|word2\b/`.

Comment: @antithesis - `join('|')` joins an array with the pipe as "glue", and as noted by ridgerunner there's parenthesis added to create the regex I posted in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `\\b` to make a single `\b`.

```
new RegExp('\\b'+stopwords[i]+'\\b' , 'g')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape backslash becasue it's inside string literal, not in the regular expression:

```
new RegExp('\\b' + stopwords[i] + '\\b' , 'g')
```

Otherwise, `'\b'` is BACKSPACE character (`'\x08'`).